# C#, .NET SMPP Devshock libraray

Tags: c#, .net, smpp, opensmpp

Please help.

When I am trying to bind to SMS center by using Devshock library (.NET/ C#),
I am getting smppBindResponse.Header.CommandStatus = **0xc2**

194 0xc2    ESME_RINVTLVLEN Invalid optional parameter length

Please tell me which parameter is not valid? Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

The error code is probably accurate, however it's very difficult to give any feedback on this since you haven't included the pdu sent.

Also the behavior for this will be vastly different depending on what SMPP provider you connect to.